# Passing arguments from main bash file to a secondary file using cat <<EOF >

Tags: bash, shell

I have not much experience using bash. I would appreciate if someone can help me.

This is my issue:

Let's say I have a main bash file called `main.sh` that looks like this:

CODE EDITTED

```
#!/bin/bash

year=2020
text="the year is: "

cat - << EOF > inside_file.sh 

#some lines here

new_text='$text$year'

echo ${new_text}

# some lines here
EOF

bash inside_file.sh
```

When I run this code I create a file called `inside_file.sh`. Inside that file I want to be able to see this:

```
#some lines here

new_text='the year is: 2020'

echo $new_text

# some lines here
```

Instead I am seeing this:

```
#some lines here

new_text='the year is: 2020'

echo 

# some lines here
```

Comment: *"If I add ... then the script says exactly that"* - isn't that what you want though? Because then when you run `inside_file.sh` it will expand the `"${new_text}"` variable. (Although you want quotes e.g. `new_text="${text}${year}"` ... `echo "\${new_text}"`)

Comment: you are right. I noticed that what I was really missing was the `''` in `new_text='${text}${year}'`

Comment: `new_text='${text}${year}'` breaks if a variable value contains a `'` character.  If you are using Bash 4.4 or later, `new_text=${text@Q}${year@Q}` is safe for all possible variable values.

Answer (score 1):

You should want your output to contain `echo "$new_text"`, not `echo $new_text`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

year=2020
text="the year is: "

cat << EOF > inside_file.sh

#some lines here

new_text='${text}${year}'

echo "\$new_text"

# some lines here

EOF
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat inside_file.sh

#some lines here

new_text='the year is: 2020'

echo "$new_text"

# some lines here
```

Comment: This can break if the variable values change.  For example, try with `text="the customer's first year is: "`.

Comment: @pjh true, I'll let the OP ask a followup question about that if they care.